БЭМ. Файловая структура. Общие блоки
Своим умом не смог понять, к сожалению. Нужна помощь.
Допустим, есть такая разметка:
<header class="header">
  <ul class="list header__list">
    <li class="list__item"></li>
    <li class="list__item header__item_active"></li>
    <li class="list__item"></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<main class="main">
  <ul class="list main__list">
    <li class="list__item"></li>
    <li class="list__item list__item_active"></li>
    <li class="list__item"></li>
  </ul>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
  <ul class="list header__list footer__list">
    <li class="list__item"></li>
    <li class="list__item list__item_active footer__item_active"></li>
    <li class="list__item"></li>
  </ul>
</footer>

...файловая структура будет выглядеть примерно так:
blocks/
    header/
        __list/
            header__list.css
        __item/
            _active/
                header__item_active.css

        header.css

    main/
        __list/
            main__list.css
        __item/
            _active/
                main__item_active.css

        main.css

    footer/
        __list/
            footer__list.css
        __item/
            _active/
                footer__item_active.css

        footer.css
    
    

Вопрос: где в этой файловой структуре (если конечно я её правильно составил) должны находится стили для блока list и его элементов?
Этот блок, вроде, общий для трёх других блоков. Надо ли дублировать его стили в папках для header, main, footer?
Как размещать стили когда происходит "микс", как этот например:  <ul class="list header__list footer__list"> ?
